# Error in data frame (..., check.names= false) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 1975, 100

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hola a todos, estoy tratando de hacer un grafico con gganimate, pero me sale este error:
Error in data frame (..., check.names= false) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 1975, 100

La tabla tiene cerca de 2256 filas y 5 columnas. Este es el código que estoy usando:

```
library(gganimate)

#PRIMERO LEO LOS DATOS Y ELIMINO LOS NAs

datos <- datos[!is.na(datos$ruido),]
datos$hora <- as.factor(datos$hora)
datos$fecha <- as.Date(datos$fecha, "%d/%m/%Y")

#AQUI GENERO UNA TABLA DE RESUMEN CON EL VALOR MEDIO DEL RUIDO
ResumenEst <- datos %>% group_by(estacion, fecha) %>% 
                       summarise(promedio = mean(ruido) 
                                 #Minima=min(ruido), 
                                 #Maxima=max(ruido), 
                                 ) %>% 
                       arrange(estacion, fecha)

ResumenEst

ruido_rangos <- ResumenEst %>%
  group_by(fecha) %>%
  mutate(rango = rank(-promedio),
         labels = paste0(" ", round(promedio)))


ruido_rangos %>%
  arrange(fecha, rango) 

ruido_rangos = as.data.frame(ruido_rangos)
str(ruido_rangos)
```

En el siguiente bloque, genero el grafico y corre sin problema

```
plot_ruido <- ggplot(ruido_rangos, aes(rango, group = estacion, 
                            fill = estacion)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = promedio), alpha = 0.9, color = "white") +
  coord_flip(clip = "off", expand = FALSE) +
  geom_text(aes(y = 0, label = paste(estacion, " ")), vjust = 0.2, hjust = 1) +
  geom_text(aes(y= promedio, label = labels, hjust = 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
  scale_x_reverse() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("cornflowerblue", "green3", "darkorange", "lightblue")) +
  guides(color = FALSE, fill = FALSE) +

  transition_states(fecha, transition_length = 1, state_length = 1, wrap= F) + 
  labs(title = 'Niveles de ruido',  
       subtitle  =  "Fecha : {closest_state}",
       caption  = "Fechas de mediciones | Fuente: SECRETARIA DE AMBIENTE") +
  theme(
    legend.position="none",
    plot.title=element_text(size=18, hjust=0.5, face="bold", colour="grey20", vjust=-1),
    plot.subtitle=element_text(size = 18, hjust=0.5, face="plain", color="grey20"),
    plot.caption =element_text(size = 10, hjust=0.5, face="plain", color="grey20"),
    axis.line=element_blank(),
    plot.margin = margin(2,2, 2, 4, "cm"), 
    plot.background=element_blank(),
    axis.text.x=element_blank(),
    axis.text.y=element_blank(),
    axis.ticks=element_blank(),
    axis.title.x=element_blank(),
    axis.title.y=element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
    panel.background=element_blank(),
    panel.border=element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_line( size=.1, color="grey80", linetype = "dashed" ),
    panel.grid.minor.x = element_line( size=.1, color="grey80", linetype = "dashed" )
  )

animate(plot_ruido, width = 600, height = 2600, fps = 30)
```

el código corre normalmente, pero justo en la ultima fila donde empieza el "animate" se estanca y sale el error.

Comment: Bienvenida Paulina a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio, me sirvió mucho para poder colocar la pregunta de forma adecuada, soy nueva en el mundo de R, y me airve de muchisima ayuda sus aportes.